# How to format accordingly a csv file before loading to an Oracle table

Tags: oracle, csv, unix, sql-loader

I have the below csv file :

```
xxxx@xxx:~/Prod/Jcs/BIN/Dash_PPLP/load/test$ cat extraction_LIA.csv
PPL_LIABILITY,2468705,Fri Sep 01 06:56:41 2017,Fri Sep 01 06:58:33 2017
```

It contains table name, rows successful, start_time and end_time.
(parsed from unix logs)

I want to format it accordingly so to make it feasible for loading into an Oracle table like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/893YL.png)

How could I format it?? How could I edit the dates accordingly so as to be loaded?

For example, a desired outcome would be:

```
 echo "$Table_name,$Success_rows,$DAY/$MONTH/$YEAR $TIME_START,$DAY/$MONTH/$YEAR $TIME_END">> load.txt
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: To load data from a file into a table you have two options: 1) use SQL*Loader ([docs here](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/SUTIL/part_ldr.htm)), or 2) use an external table ([docs here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e16536/et_concepts.htm)). Best of luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use awk to replace the Unix date with `DAY/MONTH/YEAR` format.

```
awk 'BEGIN { OFS=","; FS=","} {split($3,a," ");split($4,b," ")}
{$3=a[3]"/"a[2]"/"a[5]" "a[4];$4=b[3]"/"b[2]"/"b[5]" "b[4]}
{print}' extraction_LIA.csv >load.txt
```

**Formatted record**:

```
PPL_LIABILITY,2468705,01/Sep/2017 06:56:41,01/Sep/2017 06:58:33
```

*Note*: awk's `split` function is used here to split the 3rd and 4th columns into an array and specific elements are extracted.

Comment: Wow, thanks. That is a smart solution and works.Quick question: 

How can i do for multiple .csv files?

Comment: Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46096761/awk-to-format-csv-files-unix-solaris-awk

Comment: Changed to $4 now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No need to preprocess.  Assuming you'll use sqlldr, and the START_TIME and END_TIME columns are a DATETIME datatype (if not, they should be), construct your control file for sqlldr like this using the correct format model for the date data:

```
...
start_time  date "to_date(start_time, 'DY MON DD HH24:MI:SS YYYY')",
end_time    date "to_date(end_time, 'DY MON DD HH24:MI:SS YYYY')"
...
```

[More info on format models](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00212)