# Awk to format csv files | unix | Solaris | awk

Tags: bash, csv, unix, awk

I have multiple csv files like below:

```
~/Prod/Jcs/BIN/Dash_PPLP/load$ ls -lt *csv
-rw-rw-r--   1 tellus   tellus        81 Sep  7 14:27 extraction_MBBSCS_PPL_USAGE_IMPORT.csv
-rw-rw-r--   1 tellus   tellus        83 Sep  7 14:27 extraction_MBBSCS_PPL_INVOICE_IMPORT.csv
-rw-rw-r--   1 tellus   tellus        71 Sep  7 14:27 extraction_INVOICE.csv
-rw-rw-r--   1 tellus   tellus        69 Sep  7 14:27 extraction_USGRERUN.csv
-rw-rw-r--   1 tellus   tellus        69 Sep  7 14:27 extraction_USG.csv
-rw-rw-r--   1 tellus   tellus        72 Sep  7 14:27 extraction_LIA.csv
-rw-rw-r--   1 tellus   tellus        74 Sep  7 14:27 extraction_MSISDN.csv
```

By opening one file

```
cat extraction_LIA.csv
PPL_LIABILITY,2468705,Fri Sep 01 06:56:41 2017,Fri Sep 01 06:58:33 2017
```

The format is name, rows, start_time and end_time for each flow I want to monitor, in order to make them "loadable" to an ORACLE table.

I have made a script like this to do the transform and overwrite them each one, like below:

```
cat transform_to_load.bash
#!/bin/bash
csv_files=$(ls *.csv)
for i in $csv_files
do
x=$(nawk 'BEGIN { OFS=","; FS=","} {split($3,a," ");split($3,b," ")}
{$3=a[3]"/"a[2]"/"a[5]" "a[4];$4=b[3]"/"b[2]"/"b[5]" "b[4]}
{print}' $i)
echo $x > $i
done
```

The issue is with my nawk:

```
x=$(nawk 'BEGIN { OFS=","; FS=","} {split($3,a," ");split($3,b," ")}
    {$3=a[3]"/"a[2]"/"a[5]" "a[4];$4=b[3]"/"b[2]"/"b[5]" "b[4]}
    {print}' $i)
```

which produces the below (start time is the same as end time)

```
tellus@proetl01:~/Prod/Jcs/BIN/Dash_PPLP/load$ cat extraction_LIA.csv
PPL_LIABILITY,2468705,01/Sep/2017 06:56:41,01/Sep/2017 06:56:41
```

What I want to achieve is to format it accordingly with nawk (SunOS) like this for each one :

```
PPL_LIABILITY,2468705,01/Sep/2017 06:56:41,01/Sep/2017 06:58:33
```

Could you please help me with my nawk to output the correct format?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost near to your aim, need to correct little bit

***cause :***

Its because in your code you have,

```
{split($3,a," "); split($3,b," ")}
                         ^
                     So you get same result in end time
```

Correct it like below

***Solution :***

```
{split($3,a," "); split($4,b," ")}
                         ^
                      Fourth Column will be used
```

> Meanwhile if you are interested, you can simplify like below,

***No need of***

- `csv_files=$(ls *.csv)`
- `x=$(nawk '{..}')`
- `echo $x > $i`

Simplified version

```
$ cat test.sh
#!usr/bin/env bash

for i in *.csv; do

# Better Prefer 
# /usr/xpg4/bin/awk or /usr/xpg6/bin/awk 

    nawk '
          BEGIN{
                FS=OFS=","
          }
          function format_dt(v, a){
              split($v,a,/ /); 
              $v=a[3]"/"a[2]"/"a[5]" "a[4]
          }
          { 
              format_dt(3); 
              format_dt(4) 
          }1
         ' "$i" >tmpfile && mv tmpfile "$i"
done
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks a lot, so adjusting it to $4 will fix it, correct??

Comment: @tln_jupiter : yes as you can see `$3` meaning 3rd field/column

Comment: @tln_jupiter, glad to know it was helpful

Comment: @tln_jupiter: you can also try like this : `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}function format_dt(v, a){split($v,a,/ /); $v=a[3]"/"a[2]"/"a[5]" "a[4]}{ format_dt(3); format_dt(4) }1' file`